# Question about the principles behind AC generators

Tags: electromagnetism, electrical-engineering

I've learnt that when the normal drawn from the surface of a coil (the area vector) is in the same direction as the magnetic field, i.e. when the field is perpendicular to the coil, then there are a maximum number of flux lines passing through the coil - which means as soon as the coil is brought into the field/the field is "switched on" emf is induced in the coil as per Faraday's law.

However, in the AC generator, when a coil is placed parallel to the field (with its area vector normal to the field) maximum emf is induced, whereas when it is placed perpendicular there is no emf induced. How is this?

Also, if I were to push a coil into a magnetic field parallel to the field (making an angle of 0), would the emf induced be maximum here? More than if the coil were perpendicular?

As you can see I'm more than a little confused here, a little clarification would be great.

Comment: Have you learned about magnetic flux yet?

Comment: @DavidWhite Yeah I have, I meant magnetic flux when I said flux lines above.

Comment: Yes, it is no much clear. First - you should have a changing field somewhere.

Comment: @jaromrax But (from what I've gathered anyway) in an AC generator the field is fixed while the coil rotates, thus changing magnetic flux, thus changing the induced emf. I don't think you'd need a changing field for that?

Comment: @WillHunt - ok, sometimes it is difficult to find common language. The Faraday law speaks about $-\frac{dB}{dt}=\nabla \times E$, in the integral form, you have a changing field $B$ over area. I would look for movement, your question looks static and I have difficulties to understand. Is the picture like in http://macao.communications.museum/eng/exhibition/secondfloor/MoreInfo/2_4_1_ACGenerator.html ?

Comment: @jaromrax Right. From what I've read, if you integrate BAcosΘdΘ/dt (to get E), you'd get 3 cases where one of the 3 variables is integrated (it's one of the laws of integration). I don't know how to type it in here, but I'll link you to the original article where I read about this - http://web.mit.edu/8.02t/www/802TEAL3D/visualizations/coursenotes/modules/guide10.pdf It's the first line on page 4. Thank you for your interest :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the following discussion, assume that a rectantular coil of wire is rotating in a magnetic field, with the axis of rotation being down the length of the rectangle (e.g., the longer dimension of the rectangle).  Further assume that the axis of rotation is perpendicular to the magnetic field lines, and that all of the coil except the ends is "bathed" in the magnetic field.  For these circumstances, maximum magnetic flux is passing through the rotating coil when the plane of the coil is perpendicular to the magnetic field lines, so it would seem that maximum emf is produced at this point.  However, as non-intuitive as it seems, this is when the induced emf in the coil drops to zero, because the wires that make up both sides of the coil are moving parallel to the magnetic field lines when the coil is in this position.  As such, the charge carriers in the wires do not feel a magnetic force on them at this instant in time.  As the coil continues to turn in the magnetic field, it soon gets to the point where the plane of the coil is parallel to the magnetic field lines, and the wire on each side of the coil is cutting through the magnetic field lines at a 90 degree angle and at the maximum rate, which is causing the maximum rate of change of magnetic flux in the coil, leading to the maximum emf at that point in the rotational cycle.  Thus, maximum emf is generated when the wires of the coil are cutting through the magnetic field lines at the maximum rate, which occurs when the coil has minimum magnetic flux "flowing" through it.

Regarding pushing a coil into a magnetic field, the maximum emf is induced in the coil whenever you are changing the magnetic flux in the coil at the maximum rate.    This will occur when the coil is oriented such that the plane of the coil is perpendicular to the magnetic field, which seems "opposite" to the comments above.  However, keep in mind that the two different motions of the coil (e.g., one case is rotating the coil in a magnetic field while the other case is manually pushing a coil into a magnetic field) lead to two different orientations that produce maximum emf.  In both cases, the maximum emf is produced when the coil is experiencing the maximum *rate of change* of magnetic flux, which is not necessarily the point where the maximum magnetic flux through the coil occurs.

Comment: Thank you, that really cleared things up! One more question - what actually causes this induced emf to flow? I don't think a magnetic field can do work, so is the emf caused by the mechanical work done to rotate the coil (or pushing it into the field)? Or is it something else?

Comment: A moving charge in a magnetic field experiences a force that is at right angles to its velocity and the magnetic field direction.  Since there are "free electrons" in conducting wires (i.e., not bound to individual atoms), these electrons experience a force when moving perpendicular to a magnetic field.  This force induces an emf in the wire, and causes electrons to move in the direction of the force that they experience.

Comment: @WillHunt, additional comment (my 5 min. time limit expired): There is an opposing force which tries to prevent the generation of current in a closed loop experiencing an induced emf (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenz's_law), so some type of shaft work  must be done to generate this current.

Comment: I'll go through some Wikipedia articles for more about magnetism, I find this topic really interesting. Thanks for all the help :)